# Where is the current wallpaper stored?

Tags: xfce

Does anyone know where the current wallpaper is stored in xfce4?

I am using SLiM and I want to symlink the SLiM background to whatever my current wallpaper is so I don't have to manually change it every time.

Answer (score 4):

The are 2 possible locations:

For the user check

```
~/.local/share/xfce4/backdrops/
```

Globally check the system wide path

```
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops
```

To share a wallpaper between SLiM and your desktop, rename the used theme background, then create a link from your desktop wallpaper file to the default SLiM theme:

```
mv /usr/share/slim/themes/default/background.jpg{,.bck}
ln -s /path/to/mywallpaper.jpg /usr/share/slim/themes/default/background.jpg
```

Comment: I've found those, but that's only the directory where XFCE populates the backgrounds list under desktop settings. I want to know where I can find the currently set background so I can create a symlink to that specific file.

Comment: Have you tried to look also into /usr/share/backgrounds/xfce/? This wallpaper is a personal loaded image or is from the XFCE install?

Comment: A personal image. I want a way to change my xfce wallpaper and have SLiM automatically change with it. I used to have the background.png in my SLiM theme symlinked to ~/.background.png before I started using xfce. I would like to acheive the same result.

Comment: Well in that case if you know the image name you can search for it and them follow the procedure in the updated aswer.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old question as a recent convert to arch and xfce4 I have also been puzzling over this issue. I finally found a solution and thought I'd post it here in case it's of use to others.
e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash -
#
# define xfce4 xml file that holds info about desktops 
# 
DESKTOP="/home/$(id -un)/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-desktop.xml"
#
# define xpath that will extract current desktop background file name
# (NB I am no expert in xpaths and there is probably a much more elegant way
#  to do this but this works for me)
#
XPATH='(//property[@name="workspace0"]/property[@name="last-image"])[last()]/@value'
#
# use xmllint utility to apply xpath to file and extract file path and name
#
IMAGE=$(xmllint --xpath "string(${XPATH})" "${DESKTOP}")
#
# display the file info extracted
#
echo Current Wallpaper File = ${IMAGE}
#
# rest of script........
#
```

xmllint is provided by the libxml2 package.

Comment: actually, for multiple monitor config, `xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/$(xrandr|awk '/\<connected/{print "monitor"$1}')/workspace0/last-image`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but recently I tried figuring this myself.
This is my solution:

Create a file named `screenLocker` inside `/usr/bin/`

Put the following inside (replace YOUR_CURRENT_THEME with your theme):

```
#!/bin/bash
ln -fs $(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor0/workspace0/last-image) \ 
/usr/share/slim/themes/YOUR_CURRENT_THEME/background.png && slimlock
```

then:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/screenLocker
```

and add/edit keyboard shortcut to use command `/usr/bin/screenLocker`

Now every time you change desktop wallpaper your lock screen will match.

Answer (score 1):

This will list all the backgrounds

```bsh
xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -l | grep last-image
```

then use the above output to get the path of the wallpaper.

for eg:

```bsh
xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitorVNC-0/workspace0/last-image
```

Comment: Combined into a single command: `xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -l | grep last-image | xargs -n1 -- xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p`

Answer (score -1):

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/$(xrandr|awk '/\<connected/{print "monitor"$1}')/workspace0/last-image
```

This will fetch the connected monitor name from xrandr, then get the wallpaper setting for it.

What a waste of time finding this out

Comment: Doesn't work for me: my monitor is `DVI-I-1`, but the background is stored under `/backdrop/screen0/monitorDVI-0/workspace0/last-image` (I think; the entry for `/backdrop/screen0/monitor0/workspace0/last-image` appears to be stale).